# With the HTML5 video tag, will Firefox use the fallback if the format isn't supported?

Tags: firefox, html, video

We don't have the .ogv format available from the encoder in our system, but I would like to use the HTML5 Video tag with an MP4 source for those browsers that support it--unfortunately, Firefox does not support MP4.

After some experimentation, it seems that once you put the video tag in Firefox, it will figure out if any of the provided sources are playable, and if none of them are, it will do nothing.  It will also ignore the nested fallback object.  This is technically the correct behavior per the HTML5 spec, but it seems that if Firefox can't play the MP4 source it should just render the inner object tags.

I know there are JavaScript techniques for testing whether a browser "canPlayType", but I would rather avoid the JavaScript insertion of the video tag.

Am I correct that Firefox ignores the internal fallback markup in a video *whether* or *not* the video tag sources are supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is technically the correct behavior per the HTML5 spec

I believe you have your answer. ;)

I know Firefox strives for compliance so I doubt they would go against the grain here. Although, I'll admit, it does seem odd that the spec doesn't allow for a fallback.